# WCF: How to handle errors when calling another WCF service?

Tags: wcf, error-handling

I have a project where I should write WCF service that calls another WCF service. It looks as following:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAsurService
{
    [OperationContract(ReplyAction = AsurService.ReplyAction_GetCatalogList)]
    Message GetCatalogList();

public Message GetCatalogList()
{
    // The external client service
    GetNsiClient client = new GetNsiClient();

    authContext auth = new authContext
    {
        company = "asur_nsi",
        password = "lapshovva",
        user = "dogm_LapshovVA"
    };

    catalogs catalogs = client.getCatalogList(auth);
```

How can I handle errors in this case? Can I use standard fault contract approach like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class AsurDataFaultException
{
    private string reason;

    [DataMember]
    public string Reason
    {
        get { return reason; }
        set { reason = value; }
    }
}

public Message GetCatalogList()
{
    // The external client service
    GetNsiClient client = new GetNsiClient();

    authContext auth = new authContext
    {
        company = "asur_nsi",
        password = "lapshovva",
        user = "dogm_LapshovVA"
    };

    catalogs catalogs = null;
    try
    {
        catalogs = client.getCatalogList(auth);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        AsurDataFaultException fault = new AsurDataFaultException();
        fault.Reason = "The error: " + exception.Message.ToString();
        throw new FaultException<AsurDataFaultException>(fault);
    }
```

Or something else?

Thank you in advance.

Goran

Answer (score 0):

If the remote WCF service's failure causes a failure of your code, then obviously you should throw a fault but that fault **should not expose the inner details** of the remote WCF service or its exception, like so:

```
catch (Exception exception) 
{
    // Indicate all that you may expose -- that the data is unavailable.
    DataUnavailableFault fault = new DataUnavailableFault();
    throw new FaultException<DataUnavailableFault>(fault); 
}
```

You may of course also use a retry mechanism, but obviously if what you end up with is a failure in the remote service, you should indicate that to your caller by throwing an appropriate fault.